# Why does $ not work with values of type String (and only with the string literals directly)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following object which mimic an enumeration:

```
object ColumnNames {
     val JobSeekerID = "JobSeekerID"
     val JobID = "JobID"
     val Date = "Date"
     val BehaviorType = "BehaviorType"   
}
```

Then I want to group a DF by a column. The following does not compile:

```
userJobBehaviourDF.groupBy($(ColumnNames.JobSeekerID))
```

If I change it to

```
userJobBehaviourDF.groupBy($"JobSeekerID")
```

It works.

How can I use `$` and `ColumnNames.JobSeekerID` together to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$` is a Scala feature called [string interpolator](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html).

> Starting in Scala 2.10.0, Scala offers a new mechanism to create strings from your data: String Interpolation. String Interpolation allows users to embed variable references directly in processed string literals.

Spark leverages string interpolators in Spark SQL to [convert $"col name" into a column](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala#L43-L47).

```
scala> spark.version
res0: String = 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT

scala> :type $"hello"
org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName
```

`ColumnName` type is a subtype of `Column` type and that's why you can use `$`-prefixed strings as column references where values of `Column` type are expected.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
val c: Column = $"columnName"
scala> :type c
org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

> How can I use $ and ColumnNames.JobSeekerID together to do this?

You cannot.

You should either map the column names (in the "enumerator") to the `Column` type using `$` directly (that would require changing their types to `Column`) or using [col](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@col(colName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) or [column](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@column(colName:String):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) functions when `Columns` are required.

> **col(colName: String): Column** Returns a Column based on the given column name.
>
> **column(colName: String): Column** Returns a Column based on the given column name.

### `$`s Elsewhere

What's interesting is that Spark MLlib uses `$`-prefixed strings for ML parameters, but in this case `$` [is just a regular method](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/param/params.scala#L717).

```
protected final def $[T](param: Param[T]): T = getOrDefault(param)
```

It's also worth mentioning that (another) `$` string interpolator is used in [Catalyst DSL](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/dsl/package.scala#L142-L149) to create logical `UnresolvedAttributes` that could be useful for testing or Spark SQL internals exploration.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.dsl.expressions._
scala> :type $"hello"
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedAttribute
```

### String Interpolator in Scala

The string interpolator feature works (is resolved to a proper value) at compile time so either it is a string literal or it's going to fail.

`$` is akin to the `s` [string interpolator](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html#the-s-string-interpolator):

> Prepending `s` to any string literal allows the usage of variables directly in the string.

Scala provides three string interpolation methods out of the box: `s`, `f` and `raw` and you can write your own interpolator as Spark did.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use `$` with string literals(values) If you want to use `ColumnNames` you can do as below

```
userJobBehaviourDF.groupBy(userJobBehaviourDF(ColumnNames.JobSeekerID))

userJobBehaviourDF.groupBy(col(ColumnNames.JobSeekerID))
```

From the [Spark Docs for Column](http://%20%20%20df(%22columnName%22)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20On%20a%20specific%20%60df%60%20DataFrame.%20%20%20%20col(%22columnName%22)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20A%20generic%20column%20no%20yet%20associated%20with%20a%20DataFrame.%20%20%20%20col(%22columnName.field%22)%20%20%20%20%20//%20Extracting%20a%20struct%20field%20%20%20%20col(%22%60a.column.with.dots%60%22)%20//%20Escape%20%60.%60%20in%20column%20names.%20%20%20%20$%22columnName%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Scala%20short%20hand%20for%20a%20named%20column.), here are different ways of representing a column:

> ```
> df("columnName")            // On a specific `df` DataFrame.
> col("columnName")           // A generic column no yet associated with a DataFrame.
> col("columnName.field")     // Extracting a struct field
> col("`a.column.with.dots`") // Escape `.` in column names.
> $"columnName"               // Scala short hand for a named column.
> ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a reference to "only use $ with string literals(values)"?
BTW, there's a slight difference. $ converts string literal to a ColumnName object, while col() converts string to Column object. Also, there's a org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit() function. Are lit() and col() the same? Thanks.

Comment: you can see here for the representation of column https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html

Comment: Oh I think I made a mistake. lit() is to "Creates a Column of literal value. " It is different.

Comment: it's interesting that `column` function is not listed, isn't it?

Comment: yeah, didn't noticed before.